# Ocorreu um problema ao analisar o pacote

Tags: android, ionic, apk

sempre desenvolvi apps tranquilamente e uso o meu celular **Xiaomi Mi6** para testar os aplicativos que eu desenvolvo, só que de uma hora pra outra, não consigo testar nenhum aplicativo que eu mesmo estou desenvolvendo, se a pessoa baixar meu APK ele funciona normalmente em outro dispositivo, exceto no meu,

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Tenta adicionar no seu `config.xml` dentro da plataforma Android a seguinte preferência:  `<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />`

Comment: Não funcionou amigo, obrigado pela ajuda de qualquer forma